# IE Open or Save dialog appears instead of Read/Edit SP dialog

Tags: 2010

This issue appears to only be affecting one user on a network.
We have Sharepoint 2010, and the user in question is connecting to the office network on a laptop via ethernet. Her system is running Windows 7 Professional and she has Office 2013 installed. All testing done with Internet Explorer 10.

Expected behavior:
When clicking on an object in a document library a Sharepoint dialog box pops up asking if the user wants to Read or Edit the document.

Actual behavior (for just this user):
Intermittently, instead of the Read/Edit dialog box, the user will get the non-Sharepoint download-this-file dialog tab at the bottom of the web browser. This tab will prompt the user to either save or open the file.

The following is just a sample of the type of erroneous image - it is not a screenshot from within our system:
[image: Sample of message]
<sub>(source: [cloudnetworks.com.au](https://www.cloudnetworks.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/image148.png))</sub>
]

Additional notes:

1. We have tried testing in multiple document libraries on different subsites to no avail.
2. This is a new issue - the user did not have this issue as recently as last month.
3. The same exact file will sometimes produce one dialog, and sometimes produce the other. We have been unable to determine the criteria for one or the other.

Comment: Can you compare Add-ons on IE between this client and another client that doesn't have this problem? Focus on SharePoint OpenDocuments add-on.
One time I had to reinstall Office.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I tried repairing the Office 2013 installation, to no avail.
I took a look at that particular Add-on and it is enabled and up to date - I do not know personally how to verify that it is functioning properly.